# html5: Input Field Using @fontface, non-system fonts. Is this possible

Tags: fonts, html, css

Quick question, is it possible to have an input field in a form use a non-system font in html5 and css3?  So if someone types in the form field the text could be something like gotham?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special to do here, just setup a `@font-face` as normal:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Delicious";
   src: url("Delicious-Bold.otf"); 
}

.myinput {
   font-family: "Delicious";
}
```

This works for me on Chrome for OSX

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. I just had to remove the @font-face font from a site that I applied it on or else I'd link to a working example for you.

Here's what I had for the CSS though:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'QuicksandBook';
    src: url('/media/fonts/Quicksand_Book.eot');
    src: local('Quicksand Book'), local('QuicksandBook-Regular'), url('/media/fonts/Quicksand_Book.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html, body,
input, textarea {
    font-family: QuicksandBook, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```